# Error CS2001 Source file 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\MyHololens01\Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Runtime\TMP_FontAsset.cs' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens

I have installed Hololens Emulator, Visual studio 2017, and Unity 3D and done all the necessary settings.

Now I want to run my Unity project on Hololens Emulator, but unfortunately when I am running the .sln generated file in Visual Studio, I am facing this error:

> Error CS2001 Source file 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\MyHololens01\Packages\com.unity.textmeshpro\Scripts\Runtime\TMP_FontAsset.cs' could not be found

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I am not sure which unity version are you using, but this is what I did to resolve my error (assuming you are using Unity 2018.2.12f1 or 2018.2.11f1):

## (1) Uninstall TextMesh Pro

1. Open your Unity project.
2. Click on **Windows** from the Unity Menu
3. Select **Package Manager**
4. Find **TextMesh Pro** package and select it
5. Click on **Remove** located on the top right corner
   [Screenshot here to help you. I already uninstalled mine, so you should see Remove instead of Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM0wX.png)

## (2) You must delete the previously generated UWP Visual Studio Solution in your previous build.

## (3) Build your project in Unity

## (4) If using older version of Unity:

If you see a folder named **TextMesh Pro** inside your **Asset** folder, delete it and then follow the steps above to rebuild it. **Make sure you delete the previously generated UWP solution**.

Hopefully this resolve your issue.